# Check if one file path exists inside another?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have the following 2 pathname strings (windows environment):

```
roaming = `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\`
```

and

```
bin = `%AppData%\.minecraft\bin`
```

<s>How do I check that `bin` exists inside `roaming`?</s> Is there a way to get a boolean value saying that `bin` is nested in `roaming`

**NOTE:** fs.exists(), existsSync(), and access() all check the directory against *the **current** directory*. I want to check against a ***specified** directory* without changing the current directory

**NOTE 2:** Replacing `%AppData%` is an elegant solution, but I need one that uses the environment to do that evaluation, so it can handle things like windows folder redirects as well.

**EXAMPLE:** Say a user gives me this repository path via html input in electronjs on windows 10(not looking for a windows/electron specific answer, just an example) (stored as a string in `repo_var`):

`%AppData%\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\SOME_REPOSITORY\`

Say the user then gives me this folder (stored as a string in `file_var`):

`D:\SOME_NETWORK_DRIVE\USER_PROFILES\THIS_USER\AppData\Roaming\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\SOME_REPOSITORY\SOME_DIRECTORY\SOME_FILE.SOME_EXTENSION`

On this specific client `%AppData%` evaluates to `D:\SOME_NETWORK_DRIVE\USER_PROFILES\THIS_USER\AppData\Roaming` in PowerShell

I want to run this:

```
const { exec } = require( "child_process" );
exec( "git -C " + repo_var + " log --follow -p -- " + file_var )
```

I want to make sure that file_var is a file in the repository (repo_var) before running that shell command (from nodejs) in powershell TO AVOID RUNNING ERRONEOUS COMMANDS FROM THE HOST ENVIRONMENT (POWERSHELL IN THIS EXAMPLE)

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve (expected result)? What have you tried so far & with what results?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' I'm not sure what isn't clear. There isn't much to try. The closest function that I know of in documentation is fs.exists(), but that only checks that a file exists, it doesn't check if it exists within another file path.

Comment: Why not test both paths against `fs.exists()` or `access()`?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' both of those check the file against current directory. That won't work. I need to check the second path against the first one

Comment: Still not clear what exactly are you trying to achieve. Post more code and an example of desired result. And what do you mean by "current" directory? CWD makes no difference when using absolute paths.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' The script isn't only handling absolute paths. This was just an example. Posting more code won't add context. This is because the pathname strings aren't defined in script, they are passed in by user. The script needs to evaluate if the second path passed by the user exists inside the first provided path. I also edited the desired result in the question. I don't know how to make that clearer

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' added problematic code example

Comment: I think I understand, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should be using [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) so the backslashes don't get wiped:

```js
const roaming = String.raw`C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming`;
const bin = String.raw`%AppData%\.minecraft\bin`;
```

Next, you should use [`fs.existsSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) to do the test:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
if (fs.existsSync(bin.replace(/%AppData%/, roaming)) {
    // directory exists
} else {
    // directory doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but what about path shenanigans like file sync and folder redirection? for example, say `"My Documents"` folder on my local `C:` drive was redirected to a well-nested profile folder on network drive `D:` and I wanted to check synchrony of a file `"My Documents\SUBFOLDER\FILE.EXT"` against the same file, but on the network drive.

Comment: Is it just that you want to compare contents of two files?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' No. It's for error handling. I'm running `git` commands from nodejs, with the `-C` option (`git -C "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming" log --follow -p -- "%AppData%\.minecraft\bin\somefile.json"`) I need to know that the second path exists inside the firsts, before executing, so that I avoid sending erroneous commands to PowerShell.

Comment: Does this work both on mac and Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine a specific delimiter, like `\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\` in this case, you can determine the desired file path and and test it against `fs.access` (promisified in this example).

```js
let delimiter = `\\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\\`,
    repo_var = `%AppData%\\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\\SOME_REPOSITORY\\`,
    file_var = `D:\\SOME_NETWORK_DRIVE\\USER_PROFILES\\THIS_USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\SOME_APPDATA_FOLDER\\SOME_REPOSITORY\\SOME_DIRECTORY\\SOME_FILE.SOME_EXTENSION`,
    test_var = repo_var.substring(0, repo_var.indexOf(delimiter))
               + file_var.substring(file_var.indexOf(delimiter))

console.log('this file will be checked', test_var)

fs.promises.access(test_var, fs.constants.F_OK)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('file exists', test_var)
  }
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('file doesn\'t exist', test_var)
  }
```